# Why a string is displayed differently inside a list and outside in python?

Tags: python, string, encoding

I am scraping a web page and I get what I guess is a utf-8 text.So, the following happens:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
import json

url = '....'
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
a = u'\u0391\u0391\u039b\u0395\u039d'
print a
ΑΑΛΕΝ
print [a]
[u'\u0391\u0391\u039b\u0395\u039d']
```

Any ideas why the second time is not displayed as the first ?

Answer (score 3):

`print` calls `str` implicitly on the arguments, but `str` for a list call `repr` on all of the inner elements.  e.g.:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'world'
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'hello'
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print repr(f)
hello
>>> print f
world
>>> print [f]
[hello]
```

Comment: Is there a way to display it properly ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by properly... `', '.join(str(x) for x in f)` is a start...